# Dictionary values deleted after each iteration

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, key-value

```
def buildCodeDict():
    auto_dict = {"A": "Alpha", "B": "Bravo", "C": "Charlie", "D": "Delta", "E": "Echo", "F": 'Foxtrot', "G": "Golf",
                 "H": "Hotel", "I": "India", "J": "Juliet", "K": "Kilo", "L": "Lima", "M": "Mike", "N": "November",
                 "O": "Oscar", "P": "Papa", "Q": "Quebec", "R": "Romeo", "S": "Sierra", "T": "Tango", "U": "Uniform",
                 "V": "Victor", "W": "Whiskey", "X": "X-ray", "Y": "Yankee", "Z": "Zulu"}

    input_dict = {"A": str, "B": str, "C": str, "D": str, "E": str, "F": str, "G": str, "H": str, "I": str, "J": str,
                  "K": str, "L": str, "M": str, "N": str, "O": str, "P": str, "Q": str, "R": str, "S": str, "T": str,
                  "U": str, "V": str, "W": str, "X": str, "Y": str, "Z": str}

    print("Please enter your preferred ICAO word for each letter of the English alphabet (or ENTER for auo-entry):")
    for key in auto_dict:
        keyword = input(str(key) + ": ")
        if keyword == "":
            print(str(auto_dict[key]))
            auto_dict[str(key)] = auto_dict[key]
            # uses a word from auto_dict if the user selects ENTER instead of a custom word
            print("Input dict: ", auto_dict)
        auto_dict[key] = keyword
    return auto_dict
```

[Console shows dictionary values are deleted after each iteration.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssvnF.png)

As I've shown here, I have two dictionaries defined in a function. The first has autogenerated values for each letter of the alphabet, and the second leaves those values up to the user. The user can either type a word when prompted with a letter, or press enter to have that word generated from the list of autogenerated values.

The problem is, when I run the function I end up with an empty dictionary. I tried printing the values in the dictionary for each iteration as I've shown in the screenshot, and it seems that every time the program moves to a new key, the value in the previous key is deleted. Any idea what is causing this to happen?

Comment: [Why you should not upload code/data/errors as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question) - also note that PyCharm is just an editor with a debugger, it doesn't actually run your code, that's just Python. So if your code doesn't work, it's not PyCharm and it's almost never Python, it's your code.

Comment: Now, from your screenshot, check out for line 19. That's your "error". You're assigning the current value from `key` an empty string, as `keyword` will be `""` is you press Enter on the console.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly it. I may have gotten a bit lazy with my if-else statements.

Answer (score 0):

That's how I fixed it:

```
# Beware that only auto_dict is used on your posted script as text,
# which differs from your screenshot.
#
# I fixed it in here.
def buildCodeDict():
    auto_dict = {"A": "Alpha", "B": "Bravo", "C": "Charlie", "D": "Delta", "E": "Echo", "F": 'Foxtrot', "G": "Golf",
                 "H": "Hotel", "I": "India", "J": "Juliet", "K": "Kilo", "L": "Lima", "M": "Mike", "N": "November",
                 "O": "Oscar", "P": "Papa", "Q": "Quebec", "R": "Romeo", "S": "Sierra", "T": "Tango", "U": "Uniform",
                 "V": "Victor", "W": "Whiskey", "X": "X-ray", "Y": "Yankee", "Z": "Zulu"}

    input_dict = {"A": str, "B": str, "C": str, "D": str, "E": str, "F": str, "G": str, "H": str, "I": str, "J": str,
                  "K": str, "L": str, "M": str, "N": str, "O": str, "P": str, "Q": str, "R": str, "S": str, "T": str,
                  "U": str, "V": str, "W": str, "X": str, "Y": str, "Z": str}

    print("Please enter your preferred ICAO word for each letter of the English alphabet (or ENTER for auo-entry):")
    for key in input_dict:
        keyword = input(str(key) + ": ")
        if keyword == "":
            print(str(input_dict[key]))

            # You don't need this line anymore:
            # auto_dict[str(key)] = auto_dict[key]

            # Instead use this:
            # uses a word from auto_dict if the user selects ENTER instead of a custom word
            keyword = auto_dict[key]
        
        input_dict[key] = keyword
        print("Input dict: ", input_dict)
    return input_dict

if __name__ == '__main__':
    buildCodeDict()
```